# ¿Cómo tener las celdas del mismo tamaño usando itext 7 C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

Estoy usando `IText 7` para crear archivos pdf pero al momento de crear una tabla y crear las celdas de la misma, las celdas que no tienen contenido se ponen más pequeñas.

Lo que deseo es que todas las celdas mantengan el mismo ancho asi no contengan texto.

En la imagen se ve que las celdas que tienen mayor texto cogen mayor tamaño, y las que tienen menor texto se encogen y lo que deseo es que las celdas de una misma fila contengan el mismo tamaño y mantengan el mismo alineamiento para las demás ya que mostrando los bordes verticalmente derechos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo

```
public ActionResult createPDF()
        {

            string fechaGenerada = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
            string nombreUnico = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhh:mm:ss");
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            PdfWriter pw = new PdfWriter(ms);
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pw);
            Document document = new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.LETTER);
            document.SetMargins(75, 35, 70, 35);

            String pdfname = "TICKET_INGRESO_"+nombreUnico+".pdf";
            document.SetMargins(75, 35, 70, 35);

            PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA_BOLD);

            Table tablaTitulo = new Table(1).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cell = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(ConstantesFormato.texto1)).SetFontSize(14).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            tablaTitulo.AddCell(cell);

            document.Add(tablaTitulo);

            Table tbReglas = new Table(1).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cellReglas = new Cell();

            crearCeldaRegla(tbReglas, cellReglas, ConstantesFormato.texto2);
            crearCeldaRegla(tbReglas, cellReglas, ConstantesFormato.texto3);
            crearCeldaRegla(tbReglas, cellReglas, ConstantesFormato.texto4);
            crearCeldaRegla(tbReglas, cellReglas, ConstantesFormato.texto5);
            crearCeldaRegla(tbReglas, cellReglas, ConstantesFormato.texto6);

            document.Add(tbReglas);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));

            Table tbHeader = new Table(1).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cellHeader = new Cell();
            crearCeldaHeader(tbHeader, cellHeader, ConstantesFormato.titulo1, font);
            crearCeldaHeader(tbHeader, cellHeader, ConstantesFormato.titulo2, font);
            document.Add(tbHeader);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));

            Table tb3filas = new Table(5).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cell3filas = new Cell();

            
            crear2Celdas(tb3filas, cell3filas, ConstantesFormato.nticket, "TCK-" + contador);
            crear2Celdas(tb3filas, cell3filas, ConstantesFormato.fecha, fechaGenerada);


            document.Add(tb3filas);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));

            Table tb9filas = new Table(5).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cell9filas = new Cell();


                crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, ConstantesFormato.contenedor, "-");

            crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, "Tmñ/Tipo", "-");


                crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, ConstantesFormato.tara, "-");


                crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, ConstantesFormato.payload, "-");


            crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, "ISO", "-");

                crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, ConstantesFormato.ffechaFab, "-");

                crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, ConstantesFormato.clase, "-");


            crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, "Precinto 1", "-");
            crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, "Precinto 2", "-");
            document.Add(tb9filas);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));

            Table tb4filas = new Table(5).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cell4filas = new Cell();

                crear2Celdas(tb4filas, cell4filas, ConstantesFormato.placa, "-");



                crear2Celdas(tb4filas, cell4filas, ConstantesFormato.transportes, "-");


                crear2Celdas(tb4filas, cell4filas, ConstantesFormato.conductor, "-");


            crear2Celdas(tb4filas, cell4filas, "Licencia", "-");
            document.Add(tb4filas);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));

            Table tbfilas4 = new Table(5).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cellfilas4 = new Cell();
            crear2Celdas(tbfilas4, cellfilas4, "Movimiento", "Ingreso");
            crear2Celdas(tbfilas4, cellfilas4, "Destino", "Devolución Cliente");

                crear2Celdas(tbfilas4, cellfilas4, ConstantesFormato.status, "-");

                crear2Celdas(tbfilas4, cellfilas4, ConstantesFormato.cliente, "-");


            document.Add(tbfilas4);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));

            Table tbObservaciones = new Table(5).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cellObservaciones = new Cell();

                crear2Celdas(tbObservaciones, cellObservaciones, ConstantesFormato.observaciones, "-");


            document.Add(tbObservaciones);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));



            Table tbAgentAduana = new Table(1).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cellAgentAduana = new Cell();
            crearCeldaFirma(tbAgentAduana, cellAgentAduana, "Ag. Aduana / Emp. Transportes");
            document.Add(tbAgentAduana);

            Table tbfilasInspector = new Table(5).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cellfilasInspector = new Cell();

                crear2Celdas(tbfilasInspector, cellfilasInspector, ConstantesFormato.inspector, "-");

            document.Add(tbfilasInspector);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));

            Table tbNota = new Table(1).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cellNota = new Cell();
            crearCelda(tbNota, cellNota, "NOTA. Para acceder a su EIR debe ingresar al portal www.imupesa.com.pe");

            document.Add(tbNota);

            document.Close();
            byte[] byteStream = ms.ToArray();
            ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.Write(byteStream, 0, byteStream.Length);
            ms.Position = 0;
            return File(ms, "application/pdf", pdfname);
            
        }

        int aleatorio(int min, int max)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            return rnd.Next(1, 999999999);
        }

        void crearCelda(Table tabla, Cell celda, String texto1)
        {
            celda = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(texto1)).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            tabla.AddCell(celda);

        }
        void crearCeldaRegla(Table tabla, Cell celda, String texto1)
        {
            celda = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(texto1)).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            tabla.AddCell(celda);

        }
        void crearCeldaHeader(Table tabla, Cell celda, String texto1, PdfFont fuente)
        {
            celda = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(texto1)).SetFontSize(14).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).SetFont(fuente);
            tabla.AddCell(celda);
        }

        void crearCeldaFirma(Table tabla, Cell celda, String texto1)
        {
            celda = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(texto1)).SetFontSize(14).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).SetBorderTop(new DashedBorder(1f));
            tabla.AddCell(celda);
        }
        void crear2Celdas(Table tabla, Cell celda, String texto1, String valor)
        {
            celda = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(texto1)).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            tabla.AddCell(celda);
            celda = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(":")).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            tabla.AddCell(celda);
            celda = new Cell(1, 3).Add(new Paragraph(valor)).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            tabla.AddCell(celda);
        }
    }
```